# Is it 'a flight' or 'flights' when two people travel together?

Tags: grammatical-number

My niece and nephew are joining us on holiday. Do I say *You will need to arrange 'a flight' or 'flights' for yourself and James to arrive on Saturday morning, the 16th*? This is assuming they will be travelling together on the same 'flight'.

Comment: @Josh61 I apologise Josh for deleting your comment. I set up two questions by mistake when trying to edit using my new phone. (I'm not the greatest technical wizard, as you may have gathered). But I take on board your suggestion that where two are travelling together it should be *a flight*.

Comment: They need to arrange ***a flight***  if they are traveling on the same airplane at the same time. If the flight is cancelled, for instance,  they'll say "our flight has been cancelled" not "our flights".

Comment: @Josh61 But if it is not quite that clear and it is something like *Arrangements have changed, you will now need to arrange "flights"/"a flight" for yourselves on Sunday*. I guess the issue here is the degree of understanding that you have that the two will be travelling together. The problem is when there is any element of uncertainty about that.

Comment: If the context is not clear and they may have to take more than one flight, the plural form would make more sense.

Comment: @Josh61 So, however small the degree of uncertainty as to whether they will be together, your suggestion is to go for *flights*. That's how I'm reading it.

Comment: That's how I'd read it. The fact that their "flights" may actually result in them travelling on the same plane at the same time may be considered a (fortunate or unfortunate, depending on their relationship) coincidence.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp In this case they are brother and sister so it is no big deal. But such delicacy of language can take on an importance when you are not too sure of the relationship. And if one transfers the question from *flight/flights* to *bed/beds*....Oh dear, let's not even go there!

Comment: Haha, well for beds I would normally say "accommodation", i.e. *"You will also need to arrange your own accommodation."* which makes no assumption about whether they will co-habitate or not.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Unless they are coming to stay with you! We've negotiated that thorny little path. But I digress...

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would expect that if you have multiple flights in mind (i.e. potentially separate for each person), you would say "flights", but if you expect they only need one flight, you would say "a flight".

However, since in this context the word "flight" is shorthand for "a flight booking" or "an airplane ride ticket", then the plural may make sense. *"You will need to arrange flights [bookings/tickets] for yourself and James..."*

Comment: Yes. I think this is what prompted my question. It is probably more straightforward if you say *tickets*, or *bookings*.